# Windows phone 8.0 on 7.8

Tags: windows-phone

Will a windows phone application targeted for 8 work on 7.8? I cannot see to get a straight answer on this. Ultimately want to build an app that will work on 7.8 and 8.0. Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Windows Phone 8 apps won't work on WP 7.x devices but WP 7.x apps will work on WP8. So you can create a new WP7 project and have it run on both. If you're not using any WP8-specific features, I'd recommend that approach.

If you are using WP8 features for the WP8 version, then you can create two separate projects (one targetting 7.1 and the other 8.0) and share common code. If you follow the MVVM pattern, this makes it a lot easier as your logic is not tied to a specific view. You can create Portable Class Library to share common code or you can link class files between projects so that you're maintaining one file but it's accessible from both projects.

The [Nokia development page](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Co-development_for_Windows_Phone_7/8_and_Windows_8_guide) has a good article on how to go about writing for both versions.